# Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The provider 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' is not registered

Tags: oracle, ssis, database-connection, ssas, oracle12c

I am trying to import data from Oracle into SSAS. I am able connect to Oracle Database..I can also see all the tables and views..but its giving me following error while importing tables.

error: **Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The provider 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' is not registered.The following system error occurred:  Class not registered A connection could not be made to the data source with the Name of 'XYZ'.**

I have installed 32 bit oracle client 12C. On development server I am able to import data in SSAS cube from Oracle with same configuration but not on my production server.

Please help me sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include OLE DB provider for installation? Default Oracle Instance Client does not include the OLE DB provider.

Comment: I have installed only 32 bit 12c Oracle client. Do I need to install OLE DB provider separately ? . But on Dev server same configuration is working fine. Please suggest. @WernfriedDomscheit